# mysqldump creates Table instead of a View

Tags: mysql

I have a script on server that should backup all databases, but it saves all views as tables. I suppose that I have a keys for `mysqldump` wrong. Can anyone help me to get them right?

### script:

```
mysql -uroot -pxxx -e "SHOW DATABASES;" > dblist.txt
exec < dblist.txt
read dbname1
while read dbname
    do
       mysqldump -uroot -pxxx -r ${dbname}.sql --routines --add-drop-database --default-character-set=cp1251 --create-options --complete-insert $dbname || echo -e "${dbname} backup failed!"
    done
```

### Output:

```
--
-- Temporary table structure for view `Events`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Events`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `Events`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `Events` (
  `id` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `name` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `subname` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `description` tinyint NOT NULL,
  ...
  `subname_e` tinyint NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

### What actually in DB:

```
MySQL [(none)]> show create table `Events`\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            View: Events
     Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `db`.`Events` AS select `e`.`id` AS `id`,`e`.`name` AS `name`,`e`.`subname` AS `subname`,`e`.`description` AS `description`, ... `e`.`subname_e` AS `subname_e` from (`db1`.`Events` `e` left join `db2`.`EventsSitesLogo` `s` on((`e`.`id` = `s`.`eventid`)))
character_set_client: utf8
collation_connection: utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql-server version: **5.1.73**

**EDIT1**: I stumbled upon information that the table I see in dump-file is a temporary table that is meant to ensure that views that are made on the base of other view(s) are made correctly, while actual algorithms for views' creation are always at the end of backup. However, my file ends with these lines:

```
/*end of normal tables dump*/    

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'db'
--
```

Nothing more. No views. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the thing that helped me in the end was this line:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --allow-keywords -QqceKf --routines --create-options --flush-privileges --insert-ignore -r /home/kov/db.sql -uroot -pxxx db
```

I am not sure what option helped in the end, but I suppose it is either `--allow-keys` or `-K`. I will probably investigate it later if I'll have a time. If I do I'll be sure to share my findings.

Comment: This answer worked for me - but it's confusing.  The file generated creates tables temporarily, then drops them and creates views...  So looking at the file I initially said "This still creates tables"

Comment: The tables are created, dropped, and then views created even with just `--opt`. I am also confused by why.

Comment: As to why. I just found out, by reading mthe mysqldump source... http://www.iskm.org/mysql56/mysqldump_8c_source.html  "Create a table with the same name as the view and with columns of the same name in order to satisfy views that depend on this view. The table will be removed when the actual view is created." - makes sence, the views may not be created in right order to satisfy dependencies. Creating temporally tables first, allows ceating the 'early' views that rely on columns in later views. If have no 'dependencies' like this its relatively harmless.